Maui.Storage.Preferences Not Persisting Values After App Closure (.NET 8)
I'm encountering a challenge with Maui.Storage.Preferences in my .NET 8 MAUI application. I'm using Preferences.Default.Set to store values, and Preferences.Default.Get to get values. But the behavior is inconsistent.
I'm testing the app on multiple version of Android and all of them have the same issue.
Observed Behavior:

When I set a preference value, I can retrieve it successfully immediately afterward.
However, if I close the app and then relaunch it, the previously set value is lost.

Question
What steps can I take to ensure that preference values are saved persistently across app restarts in .NET 8 MAUI?
What I tried

Use Maui.Storage.SecureStorage instead of Preferences
Use Preferences.Get/Set instead of Preferences.Default.Get/Set
Specify sharedName as third parameter (used a random string)
Debug and Release mode
Set allowBackup to false in android manifest

Nuget packages
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Camera.MAUI" Version="1.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Camera.MAUI.ZXing" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="9.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="FirebaseDatabase.net" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Firestore" Version="3.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="libphonenumber-csharp" Version="8.13.47" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.92" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.92" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps" Version="8.0.92" />
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.BLE" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Maui.Audio" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="112.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="4.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Debug" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Extended.UI.Maui" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Licensing" Version="27.1.53" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Maui.Buttons" Version="27.1.53" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Maui.Core" Version="27.1.53" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Maui.DataForm" Version="27.1.53" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Maui.Inputs" Version="27.1.53" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Maui.ListView" Version="27.1.53" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Maui.Picker" Version="27.1.53" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Maui.Popup" Version="27.1.53" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Maui.TabView" Version="27.1.53" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Caching" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="zxcvbn-core" Version="7.0.92" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-android34.0'">
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection.Jvm">
    <Version>1.4.4</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.Ktx">
    <Version>1.8.4</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common">
    <Version>2.8.6</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Runtime">
    <Version>2.8.6</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.AppCheck">
    <Version>118.0.0.2</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.AppCheck.Debug">
    <Version>118.0.0.2</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.AppCheck.PlayIntegrity">
    <Version>118.0.0.2</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Auth">
    <Version>123.0.0</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Common">
    <Version>121.0.0.2</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Core">
    <Version>121.1.1.11</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Database.Connection">
    <Version>116.0.2.18</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base">
    <Version>118.5.0.2</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement">
    <Version>118.4.0.2</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks">
    <Version>118.2.0.2</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

Android Manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="edited" android:versionCode="21" android:versionName="Alpha 0.7.4">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true" android:label="ConsultaMe">
        <!-- Per posizione in background -->
        <!-- <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:directBootAware="true" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> -->
        <!-- Per mappa -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="edited" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Per posizione in background -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <!-- Per mappa (Solo se minore di 23) -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
</manifest>


I can't reproduece your problem. I created a new project and test the Preferences.Default.Set and Preferences.Default.Get. The value will not lose unless I reinstall the app.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT Using a new test project everything is fine. The problem is just on my main project. I never clear preferences so I don't know why they're cleared automatically

You may have to copy your main project to a new project step by step to find the cause.

I did some more testing and found out even files saved in Environment.SpecialFolder.AppData are erased when I close the app.

You can try to check if the third party nuget package caused that or not.

I managed to solve this problem by changing
<AndroidPackageFormat>aab</AndroidPackageFormat>

to
<AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>

In project settings.
See also: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-1710-MAUI-NET-8-Android:/10707962
